# Security risks in using ‘no @thankyou.com’ to bypass Microsoft account login during Windows 11 installation

Tags: windows, security, windows-installation, microsoft

One of the recommended methods for bypassing Microsoft account login during the Windows 11 OOBE is to attempt to log in using a locked account (**no @thankyou.com** being the most commonly recommended account to use). This would then allow Windows to be installed using a local account.

In various [discussions](https://superuser.com/questions/1744963/how-can-i-set-up-windows-11-22h2-with-a-local-account) on this general topic, there have been security concerns raised about using a locked account tied to the owner of a domain such as ‘thankyou.com’.

Suggested in a comment in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1743908/windows-11-can-i-use-it-without-logging-in-to-the-microsoft-cloud), could the domain owner be granted privileges remotely over an OS installed this way? Is there some facility in the backend of Microsoft’s servers that would allow for an attack vector like this?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ The owner of thankyou.com is Citibank. Do you think they want to hack you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citibank

Comment: I wasn’t aware that Citibank owned the domain. That puts an interesting perspective on the question. I did happen to ask the same question at security.stackexchange and they suggested I try here.

Comment: Often when people build a site they use a catch-all email address. This means that all emails routed to *@domain.extension end up in one location. It seems incredibly likely that at some point in the past they noticed nonsensical emails arriving at the no@thankyou.com email address and that [they now send all those emails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_filtering) to the digital heaven.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this many times using the following method.
It has worked every time for me.

I can't see a reason using the method you describe so if there is indeed a reason, please enlighten me.  I certainly don't know everything.

### Disable internet requirements

On the "Sign in" page, use these steps:

> - Use the "Shift + F10" keyboard shortcut to open Command Prompt.
> - Type the following command to release the current network configuration and press Enter:
>   `oobe\bypassnro`
>
>   Quick note: The command is a single phrase without spaces.
> - Computer will boot automatically, and you may need to start the out-of-box experience again.
> - Click the "I don't have internet" option.

[Source](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-windows-11-without-microsoft-account) (even though I already knew how to do this, the person I scraped this text from deserves credit)

Comment: In addition, if you already connected your wifi prior to finding out that you can't skip the microsoft login setting, you also need to put your device in airplane mode (usually a keyboard combination) or otherwise turn off wifi for this to work. Also unplug any network cable. Also, did this exact method last friday.